# JPA 2.1 / Eclipselink - Can I have @ManyToOne relationship to an abstract entity using table per class?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have an abstract @Entity with @Inheritance(strategy=TABLE_PERCLASS) called Booking.

Is it possible to have an @Entity Payment.java with a @ManyToOne relationship to the abstract class?

I wasn't sure how the column mapping would go so i tried deploying using drop and create tables and Eclipselink gives a NPE :-) at deployment time

Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [xotica-bms-pu] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Table per class implies that each concrete entity maps to a different table. That means that abstract entity has no corresponding table in the database. Consequently, the table corresponding to dependent entity (with manyToOne relationship) has no way to define a foreign key since there's no target table for the foreign key.

If you need to have ManyToOne relationship to abstract entity then you can only use JOINED or SINGLE_TABLE inheritance.

Comment: I wish eclipselink was as good as you explaining the limitation